# serialize model object with related objects to JSON

Tags: django, django-serializer

I am having a `Person` model to store person details.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)    
    birthdate = models.DateField()
```

also i am having model `PersonLogs` to store person's activity logs.

```
class PersonLogs(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I am using Django Serializer to return Person objects into JSON format as response.

```
from django.core import serializers
data = serializers.serialize("json", Person.objects.all())
```

Output :

```
{
    "model": "store.person",
    "fields": {
        "first_name": "Douglas",
        "last_name": "Adams",
        "birth_date": "1952-03-11",
    }
}
```

Now i want to return `PersonLogs` into response JSON.

Expected Output :

```
{
    "model": "store.person",
    "fields": {
        "first_name": "Douglas",
        "last_name": "Adams",
        "birth_date": "1952-03-11",
        "personlogs": [['2015-06-09 15:42:58.861540'], ['2014-06-09 15:42:58.861540'], [2013-06-09 15:42:58.861540]]
    }
}
```

I looked into official documentation but i did not get any help. [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/serialization/)

Comment: You should use Django Rest Framework; its serializers are much more flexible and can be configured to follow relationships.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I did this with the help of Rest serializer.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you want to serialize `Person` with reverse `ForeignKey` relationship. Django's serializer doesn't support that. You'll have to use Django REST Framework, for e.g., as pointed out in comments by [@DanielRoseman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104349/daniel-roseman).

But if you can compromise, the following solution will work.

```
class PersonManager(models.Manager):
    def get_by_natural_key(self, first_name, last_name, birthdate):
        return self.get(first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, birthdate=birthdate)

class Person(models.Model):
   objects = PersonManager()

   # other fields
   ...
```

Now, instead of serializing `Person`, you'll have to serialize `PersonLogs`, which will output this:

```
{
    "pk": 1,
    "model": "models.PersonLogs",
    "fields": {
        "time": "2015-06-09 15:42:58.861540",
        "person": ["Douglas", "Adams", "1952-03-11"]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use serialize template.

Give related name to `PersonLogs`

```
class PersonLogs(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person,related_name='logs')
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Create serialize templates

```
logs_template = {
    'fields': [':local'],
}
person_template = {
    'fields' :[':local',':related'],
    'related':{
         'logs':logs_template,
    }
}
```

Serialize it with below function:

```
from preserialize.serialize import serialize
finaldata = serialize(data, **person_template)
```