# Django - Unable to send prefetch_related() data with Model.objects.all()

Tags: django

Below is my **views.py**

```
def books(request):
    books = Book.objects.prefetch_related('book_stat_set').all()
    for book in books:
        for book_stat in book.book_stat_set.all():
            book.stats = book_stat # what is wrong here
            pprint(vars(book_stat)) # prints book_stat dict perfectly

    books_serial = serializers.serialize("json", books)
    return HttpResponse(books_serial)
```

Here is my **models.py**

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to="mp/", blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name

class Book_stat(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
    rating = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, default=Decimal('0.00'))
    like = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.book.title + ' by: ' + self.user.profile.full_name
```

When i send the json data it does not have `stats` dictionary inside each `fields` object, but `pprint` outputs to terminal perfectly from `views.py`

**Output**

```
[
  {
     pk: 1,
     model: 'some model',
     fields: {
        # here i want to add stats
     }
  },
  {
     pk: 1,
     model: 'some model',
     fields: {
        # here i want to add stats
     }
  }
]
```

also want to remove `pk` and `model` from reponse

Comment: you dont have any field called stats that you are trying to access in the line book.stats= book_stat

Comment: @Exprator ok, how can i add one, stats must be inside of related parent object

Comment: This question is a) a duplicate and b) has *nothing whatsoever* to do with `prefetch_related`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30729207/serialize-model-object-with-related-objects-to-json